# How to get SQL prepared statement based on user input (scanner)

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, prepared-statement, java.util.scanner

I have difficulties with creating prepared statement which SELECT and print out rows which fulfill condition:

```
SELECT ReservationStartDate, ReservationEndDate FROM treservations WHERE ReservationStartDate< **?** AND ReservationEndDate> **?**
```

"?" user input - String e.g 2019-07-09 and 2019-08-16

Im able to SELECT* with following method:

```
public static List<Reservation> getAllReservation(){
        List<Reservation> reservationsList = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM `treservations`";
        try{
            PreparedStatement ps = ConnectorDB.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()){
                Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
                reservation.setReservationID(resultSet.getInt("ReservationID"));
                reservation.setCarID(resultSet.getInt("CarID"));
                reservation.setReservationStartDate(resultSet.getString("ReservationStartDate"));
                reservation.setReservationEndDate(resultSet.getString("ReservationEndDate"));
                reservation.setPesel(resultSet.getString("Pesel"));
                reservationsList.add(reservation);
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reservationsList;
    }
```

and for example insert new rows based on user input by scanner for example:

```
public static List<Reservation> getAllReservation(){
        List<Reservation> reservationsList = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM `treservations`";
        try{
            PreparedStatement ps = ConnectorDB.connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()){
                Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
                reservation.setReservationID(resultSet.getInt("ReservationID"));
                reservation.setCarID(resultSet.getInt("CarID"));
                reservation.setReservationStartDate(resultSet.getString("ReservationStartDate"));
                reservation.setReservationEndDate(resultSet.getString("ReservationEndDate"));
                reservation.setPesel(resultSet.getString("Pesel"));
                reservationsList.add(reservation);
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return reservationsList;
    }
```

The problem is how to combine these two methods and be able to SELECT rows in DB (and than print them out) based on user scanner input.

My way of thinking:
1. We create reservation object based on user input

```
    public static Reservation clientReservationMenuInput(){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String regData = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}";
        System.out.println("2 Reservation start date (YYYY-MM-DD) ");
        String ReservationStartDate;
        while (!(ReservationStartDate=scanner.next()).matches(regData)){
            System.out.printf("Date format not correct, Please try once again\n");
        }
        System.out.println("3 Reservation end date (YYYY-MM-DD) ");
        String ReservationEndDate;
        while (!(ReservationEndDate=scanner.next()).matches(regData)){
            System.out.printf("Date format not correct, Please try once again\n");
        }
        Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
        reservation.setReservationStartDate(ReservationStartDate);
        reservation.setReservationEndDate(ReservationEndDate);
        return reservation;
    }
```

2. Created object is a parameter of `checkDatesForReservation` method
3. SQL where two parameters "?" means dates from user input
4. I need while loop to find all rows
5. At the end I need return a List

```
    public static List<Reservation> checkDatesForReservation(Reservation reservation){
        List<Reservation> reservationList = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql2= "SELECT ReservationStartDate, ReservationEndDate FROM treservations WHERE ReservationStartDate=? AND ReservationEndDate= ?";
        try{
            PreparedStatement ps = ConnectorDB.connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
            ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()){
                ps.setString(1,reservation.getReservationStartDate());
                ps.setString(2,reservation.getReservationEndDate());
                reservationList.add(reservation);
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return reservationList;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? Do you get some error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [JDBC PreparedStatement example – Select list of the records](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-select-list-of-the-records/)

```java
 public static List<Reservation> checkDatesForReservation(Reservation reservation){
        Reservation reservation = null;
        List<Reservation> reservationList = new ArrayList<>();
        String sql2= "SELECT ReservationStartDate, ReservationEndDate FROM treservations WHERE ReservationStartDate=? AND ReservationEndDate= ?";
        try{
            PreparedStatement ps = ConnectorDB.connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
            ps.setString(1,reservation.getReservationStartDate());
            ps.setString(2,reservation.getReservationEndDate());
            ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
            while (resultSet.next()){
               reservation = new Reservation();
               reservation.setReservationStartDate(rs.getString("ReservationStartDate"));
               reservation.setReservationEndDate(rs.getString("ReservationEndDate"));
               reservationList.add(reservation);
            }
        }catch (SQLException e){
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        return reservationList;
    }
```

Comment: thanks. But for some reason I'm getting reservationList - is empty. But for now I'm happy with this solution and need to take closer look.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set parameters before you execute statement.

```
        PreparedStatement ps = ConnectorDB.connection.prepareStatement(sql2);
        ps.setString(1,reservation.getReservationStartDate());
        ps.setString(2,reservation.getReservationEndDate());
        ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();
        while (resultSet.next()){
            reservationList.add(reservation);
        }
```